# I was trying to create a Proton Native App using "create-proton-app new-App" but it fails with a bunch of errors

Tags: node.js, gcc, proton-native

I cannot create a new proton application.

Command `$ create-proton-app new-App` gives following utput:

```
Creating a new Proton Native app on /home/xxxxx/new-App

Installing packages... This may take a few minutes. 

...

An error ocurred: 
 npm install has failed.

===========================================
Additional relevant Info:-
---System SolusOS----
xxx@xxxxxx-pc ~ $ uname -a

Linux xxxxxx-pc 4.17.2-78.current #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jun 24 18:21:56 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

---libisl.so----
xxx@xxxxxx-pc ~ $ ls -al /usr/lib/libisl.so*

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Sep  1 22:50 /usr/lib/libisl.so.19 -> libisl.so.19.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1673936 Aug 20 08:35 /usr/lib/libisl.so.19.1.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2891 Aug 20 08:35 /usr/lib/libisl.so.19.1.0-gdb.py

===========================================
```

Looks like the version of libisl that proton wants and the version that is already installed are creating an issue. Is it so. How I can resolve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar issues. What I did instead was follow the [manual installation procedure](https://proton-native.js.org/#/manual_install) as below:

**1. Install proton native**

```
npm i -S proton-native
```

**2. Install 3rd party dependencies**

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env babel-preset-stage-0 babel-preset-react
```

**3. Configure .babelrc***

```
{
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "stage-0",
      "react"
    ]
}
```

**4. Add startup scripts to `package.json`**

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node index.js",
    "build": "babel index.js -d bin/",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
...
```